# LinkedHashSet in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am using LinkedHashSet for storing elements. 
Here is the sample code

```
Set<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<String> ();
s.add("B");
s.add("C");
s.add("F");
```

May I know if the order is going to be preserved as my reference is of type Set but object is of type LinkedHashSet?

Comment: Read : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: Read the docs. It's literally the first sentence. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: It's probably polymorphism you need to look into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it is not even close to be duplicate

Comment: @luizfzs If one reads and understands the "program to interface" question and answers then it answers this question as well as it explains the principle behind what "Interface x = new ConcreteClass" actually means.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, the hereby question is related to order-preservation on the data structure, not related to inheritance. This question does note refer to inheritance neither to interface.

Comment: @luizfzs No. The asker knows that LinkedHashSet preserves the order but wants to know if having his variable as reference type Set changes that. Set is an Interface and LinkedHashSet a concrete implementation of that interface. The conrete implementation handles the logic as described in the question i linked. So that actually answers the question.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS. Sorry, my bad :( You are right. I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Java documentation, since [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), is a implementation of [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) the order will be according to insertion, so in your example it will be like {"B", "C", "F"}.